# Flutter/Dart: Defining a list from a variable in drop down menu

Tags: list, dictionary, flutter, variables, dart

I have a list of profile fields that I would like to create using a single widget, but I'm new to Flutter and can't seem to work out one single thing: passing a list variable through a parameter to a drop down menu. I have been able to create many drop down field widgets that work just fine, using (for example) `_countries.map()`, but now that I'm trying to convert the drop down field to a single widget as not to repeat myself, it gives me an error `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'` when I try to pass it through a variable.

I have the following code (of course removing all that I believe to be unnecessary):

```
class _ProfileDataState extends State<ProfileData> {
  final _countries = DropDownLists.countries;
  String _country;
  var listType;

  Widget profileDropDown(var list, var listType) {
    return Card(
      onTap: () async {
        AlertDialog(
          content: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            items: list.map((String value) { // <-- If I test this with _countries.map(), it works
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            isDense: true,
            value: listType,
            onChanged: (value) {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                setState(() {
                  this.listType = value;
                });
              },
          )
        )
      }
    )
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return profileDropDown(_countries, _country),
...
```

Comment: Ypu are trying to pass a List<dynamic> to a List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> thats why it gives you exception, you need to pass same type

Comment: So how do I make it the same type? I have tried defining `_countries` as `List<String>`, `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>`...

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, just forgot to define the List<String> also in the widget argument. Thanks Ridha.

Comment: Good catch  good luck